# What is a MongooseServerSelectionError

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to learn the MEAN stack right now and I'm running into an error. I have code in a file called mongoose.js that looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/details";

mongoose.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log("Database connected"))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", function() {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});
```

When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
learning_mean % node mongoose.js
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/test/learning_mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:796:32)
    at /Users/test/learning_mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:328:10
    at /Users/test/learning_mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/test/learning_mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/test/learning_mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/test/learning_mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:327:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/test/learning_mean/tst/mongoose.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

Is anyone familiar with this error and/or how I can fix it?

(mongo v5.0.3 node v14.18.0)

Comment: is your mongo service running? if you are using mac then check if MongoDB is running by using this command `brew services list`

Comment: @sachin-ananthakumar thanks, I've wasted a lot of time searching for a more complicated problem :( that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongodb-commnunity was not running. found that info with `brew services list`, started the service with the command `brew services start mongodb-community`